# How to update x and y position from the amount of tilt?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion

How can I **update x and y position** of an object from the **amount of tilt**?

I'm trying to update the **x** and y position of my **_bg** object, based on the amount of a tilt movement.

Also, if the device is put down on a table, the position should go back to it's original position;

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];

    [_motionManager startGyroUpdates];
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/30
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(updateGyro)
                                            userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}



- (void)updateFromGyro
{
    self.x += _motionManager.gyroData.rotationRate.x;
    self.y += _motionManager.gyroData.rotationRate.y;

    _bg.center = CGPointMake(self.x, self.y);
}
```

Problem is that the object doesn't stop moving, ever!

Thank you!

Comment: That would work great for resetting when "put down on the table". Not sure if it would work for tilting his background. The problem is that it will snap back to original position even when tilted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rate is the amount of change per unit time.  Thus you are setting the coordinates relative to how **quickly** the device is moving, not its actual offset.  You may want to look into its `attitude` (its actual offset from an arbitrary frame of reference).  The documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CMDeviceMotion/attitude).

Comment: Thank you, Sir, for pointing me in the right direction! The CMAttitude was exactly what I needed. =)

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful. Not sure though based on the limited data available from the question. You should probably also switch to using absolute position/rotation, not relative change between frames.

Simply set a minimum threshold. This will prevent minute movements from showing as updates:

```
if( _motionManager.gyroData.rotationRate.x > ROTATION_MIN )
{
    self.x += _motionManager.gyroData.rotationRate.x;
}
if( _motionManager.gyroData.rotationRate.y > ROTATION_MIN )
{
    self.y += _motionManager.gyroData.rotationRate.y;
}
_bg.center = CGPointMake(self.x, self.y);
```

Comment: Thank you! It's not what I was looking for, but I am actually going to need it =)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making mistake in setting new center. Try this :

```
- (void)updateFromGyro
{
    self.x = _bg.center.x + _motionManager.gyroData.rotationRate.x;
    self.y = _bg.center.y + _motionManager.gyroData.rotationRate.y;

    _bg.center = CGPointMake(self.x, self.y);
}
```

By the way, your application will keep receiving gyro updates even when you put device on table, because table's slope is not guaranteed to be 0 degree.